# How can I remove this fastener?

Tags: screws, mounting, junction-box, nails

I am trying to relocate the electrical junction box mounted on concrete wall, and there is a fastener that does not have screw head. It looks nail but with washer underneath which I have not seen before.

[image: Wall-mounted junction box with a rivet-like attachment to the wall]

I tried to drill a hole to the fastener on the other side but with no success.

Comment: Think it is called a ramset nail.  Uses a special tool to drive nails into cement.  Will probably need to grind the head off if you want that box.  If replacing the box, using a long ply bar behind the box should pull it out, but the box will not be pretty anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you will have to grind or chisel that head off.
Be sure the power is off, wear your safety glasses and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same problem with Hilti fasteners. BE SURE TO WEAR SAFETY GLASSES when doing this.  I have a diamond wheel for my Dremel hand tool. The nail metal is very hard and appears to be brittle. I put a notch and then hit it with a cold chisel, they usually pop off. I will then cut the cement back, repeat the process and fill the hole with cement patching compound.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up prying the whole box with hammer from the back.

Comment: Can use tapcon screws to install the new box, if it will be on cement wall also.  Makes removing again easier.